# JMX export Mapreduce metrics

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, jmx, jmx-exporter

I am trying to export metrics of a Hadoop cluster using JMX. It works with HDFS and resourceManager. Adding it to `HADOOP_OPTS`, `HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS`, `HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS` and `YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS`.

How can I export Mapreduce metrics of the jobs? I would like to export the job operations like maps and reduces. As the metrics that shows the Job UI in the next image:

[image: Mapreduce Job UI]

Comment: Try researching `mapreduce.map.java.opts`, `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts` and `mapred.child.java.opts` properties

Comment: @cricket_007 I just added: `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=0 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false` to thats opts, but I can't found that metrics. 


I exported `export HADOOP_OPTS="-javaagent:/opt/jmx_exporter/jmx_exporter_javaagent.jar=7173:/opt/jmx_exporter/hadoop/mapred.yml"` so I can see the metrics. But it doesn't happen the same with Mapreduce

Comment: Prometheus can't poll short lived mapreduce programs. Plus, that variable only applies to daemons. You will need to use the variables I mentioned... You'd be better off putting code into your applications that used PushGateway or some other metrics collection system like StatsD endpoint into Telegraf+Influxdb

Comment: @cricket_007 I have added the variables you mentioned but I don't see any metric exported in the port I define. How do you configure thats variables?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you can... For example, lets say you put port `7173`... That is only defined in one place, for all mapreduce jobs. You therefore cannot run more than one mapper or reducer at once on the same machine because you would get errors about that port already being allocated. Thus, why I suggested you need to instrument your code to instead *push metrics* out to an external system.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in the comments, you will have to set this config on the program driver (Runner) so that it propagates it to the mappers/reducers:

```
configuration.set("mapreduce.map.java.opts", "-Xmx1600m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8008");
```

Likewise, for the reducer, you can set the variable to `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts`.

To see if it worked. Just log into one of the datanodes running the job; and run `ps aux | grep 8008` to see if the JMX port was set correctly on the mapper or reducer process.

Caveat: The same machine can't export the same port twice. You will have to make sure this doesn't occur.